# Highlighting in SOLR with nested objects fails when i add a fq

Tags: indexing, solr

I have an object in SOLR that I want to query while highlighting the parts of the child object i require.

[Edited - More info]
It works until I add a simple `fq` which I only want applied to the parent object. Then data stops returning as it seems to apply the filter to the child object too.

example document with child object

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sourceid": "1",
        "isActive": true,
        "contentType": "parentDocument",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "1_1",
                "contentType": "job",
                "sourceid": 1,
                "Title": "Head of Operations",
                "job_description": "responsibile"
            },
            {
                "id": "1_2",
                "contentType": "job",
                "sourceid": 1,
                "Title": "Boss",
                "job_description": "Liaise"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This query works

```
http://localhost:8181/solr/people/select?
&q="Liaise"
&qf=job_description
&pf=job_description
&hl.fl=job_description
&hl.q="Liaise"
```

However adding on this - returns no results

```
&fq=isActive:true
```

I also tried adding `&hl.q="responsible"`

and some request handler details

```
  <requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/select">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">biography</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <bool name="hl">true</bool>
      <bool name="stopwords">false</bool>
      <bool name="lowercaseOperators">true</bool>
      <bool name="sow">false</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="first-components">
      <str>unicodeQuoteComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "returns no results"? Do you mean `numFound` is 0 or no highlight information is returned?

Comment: What do you get if you add `&debugQuery=on`? I would be interested in seeing what Solr returns in the `parsedquery` element.

Comment: @HectorCorrea, yes i actually mean numFound=0.

"parsedquery": "+DisjunctionMaxQuery((job_description:liaise)) ()",
"parsedquery_toString": "+(job_description:liaise) ()",